# how to change window size dynamically while working on google apps?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am using apps script and using `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog()` to create my dialog.

Is there any way to resize the dialog dynamically, say if user presses a button and  I need to display more content in the dialog ?

I tried `window.resizeBy()` and `window.resizeTo()`, but none of them work. I am working on Chrome at the moment.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: I believe you can only change size with setWidth() and setHeight() before showing the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

An Example:

```
function showDialogExample() {
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('<h1>Hello World</h1>').setWidth(600).setHeight(500);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Hello World');
}
```

- [HtmlOutput](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output)